# Can I tell if an object type casted into a parent class was originally the child class In C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

Say I have the class Animal, and another class Dog, which inherits from Animal. If I type cast a Dog object to be an Animal object, is it possible to later learn that it was originally a Dog?

To be specific, here is the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Animal {};

class Dog: Animal {};

class Owner {
  bool takeOnWalk(Animal* animalIn);
};

bool Owner::takeOnWalk(Animal* animalIn) {
  If (animalIn->isA(Dog)) {return true}; // what do I use here instead of isA?
  return false;
}

int main() {
  Dog* fido = new Dog();
  Animal* gato = new Animal();
  Owner* fred = new Owner();
  Owner->takeOnWalk(fido); //I want this to return true
  Owner->takeOnWalk(gato); //this should return false
{
```

I've experimented some with things like typeof except as far as I understand, these will tell me its an Animal once the object has been casted to Animal. Ideally, there would be some operation that tries to cast an Animal into a Dog, but returns false if the object can't be casted into a Dog.

Perhaps an important note here is that for my application, I have no control over the details of Dog and Animal and the type casting occurs in code I haven't written, so I don't see an obvious solution with generics. It seems like this kind of thing would be pretty common, so I'm probably missing something simple here. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a virtual member in the base class (`virtual ~Animal() {}` is a good choice) and `dynamic_cast<Dog>(animalIn)` (isA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The rest of the answer applies in general. But since you have no control over `Animal` and `Dog`, you can use `dynamic_cast`. This still needs `Animal` to be polymorphic.

```
bool Owner::takeOnWalk(Animal* animalIn) {
  If (dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animalIn)) {return true};
  return false;
}
```

REST: You can glean this information from [polymorphic objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects) using a combination of [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) and [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index), depending on how you want to represent it. But that is almost surely the wrong solution. Use virtual functions instead. For example:

```
class Animal
{
 public:
 virtual bool WantsToWalk() = 0 {return false;}
 virtual ~Animal(){}
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
 public:
 virtual bool WantsToWalk(){return true;}
};

class Owner {
  bool takeOnWalk(Animal* animalIn) {return animalIn->WantsToWalk();}
};
```

Comment: I think `dynamic_cast` is the way I need to go. In your example, will `dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animalIn)` return true regardless of `animalIn` because it's a pointer to an Animal and pointers can be casted more easily? Will I need to do something more like `if (dynamic_cast<Dog>(*animalIn))` ?

Comment: That's the first time I've ever seen that, giving an implementation to a pure virtual function.